# MyEclipse crash [error occurred during error reporting (printing Java stack)]

Tags: java, crash, myeclipse, kingsoft

I'm testing codes in "Spring in action". When I run my helloWorld there always a crash.
The log in the installation directory is as follows:

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x377b2674, pid=6040, tid=4188
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.3-b02 mixed mode windows-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nHook.dll+0x2674]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x37324400):  JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_in_native, id=4188, stack(0x3c100000,0x3c200000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x522e352e

Registers:
EAX=0x3c1fef54, EBX=0x00000104, ECX=0x00000104, EDX=0x3c1ff058
ESP=0x3c1fed18, EBP=0x3808d590, ESI=0x522e352e, EDI=0x3c1ff058
EIP=0x377b2674, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x3c1fed18)
0x3c1fed18:   00000000 3808dff9 522e352e 377b13db
0x3c1fed28:   3c1ff058 522e352e 00000104 37324514
0x3c1fed38:   760d8d68 3c1ff664 00000000 3c1fedc0
0x3c1fed48:   6da2d545 505c3a44 72676f72 696d6d61
0x3c1fed58:   4d5c676e 6c634579 65737069 302e3828
0x3c1fed68:   5c294147 6d6d6f43 625c6e6f 72616e69
0x3c1fed78:   6f635c79 75732e6d 616a2e6e 6a2e6176
0x3c1fed88:   772e6b64 32336e69 3638782e 362e315f 

Instructions: (pc=0x377b2674)
0x377b2664:   00 00 00 8b 7c 24 10 75 07 c1 e9 02 75 6f eb 21
0x377b2674:   8a 06 46 88 07 47 49 74 25 84 c0 74 29 f7 c6 03 


Stack: [0x3c100000,0x3c200000],  sp=0x3c1fed18,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nHook.dll+0x2674]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)

[error occurred during error reporting (printing Java stack), id 0xc0000005]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x37abb400 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6620, stack(0x3cd00000,0x3ce00000)]
  0x37ab9c00 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7704, stack(0x3cb00000,0x3cc00000)]
  0x37ab9800 JavaThread "Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=6140, stack(0x3ca00000,0x3cb00000)]
  0x37ab9000 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4624, stack(0x3c900000,0x3ca00000)]
  0x37325c00 JavaThread "DLTK indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7604, stack(0x3c600000,0x3c700000)]
  0x37325400 JavaThread "MyEclipse Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=6252, stack(0x3c400000,0x3c500000)]
  0x37325000 JavaThread "Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=7092, stack(0x3c300000,0x3c400000)]
  0x37324c00 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=7568, stack(0x3c200000,0x3c300000)]
=>0x37324400 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_in_native, id=4188, stack(0x3c100000,0x3c200000)]
  0x37323800 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=6452, stack(0x3c000000,0x3c100000)]
  0x37323400 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=8188, stack(0x3bf00000,0x3c000000)]
  0x37322c00 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=600, stack(0x39490000,0x39590000)]
  0x372f5c00 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6548, stack(0x390b0000,0x391b0000)]
  0x37f91000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7164, stack(0x39820000,0x39920000)]
  0x37efec00 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=7044, stack(0x38c30000,0x38d30000)]
  0x37efe800 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=7636, stack(0x38b30000,0x38c30000)]
  0x37d64000 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=8056, stack(0x37680000,0x37780000)]
  0x36891000 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6484, stack(0x36fc0000,0x370c0000)]
  0x36874000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2388, stack(0x36ec0000,0x36fc0000)]
  0x36873c00 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5920, stack(0x36c90000,0x36d90000)]
  0x01b98400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1224, stack(0x36540000,0x36640000)]
  0x01b96800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5872, stack(0x36440000,0x36540000)]
  0x01b95000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2768, stack(0x36340000,0x36440000)]
  0x01b8ac00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1536, stack(0x36240000,0x36340000)]
  0x01b51000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5876, stack(0x36140000,0x36240000)]
  0x01b4c400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8040, stack(0x36040000,0x36140000)]
  0x01ab9400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=8016, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01b49000 VMThread [stack: 0x35f40000,0x36040000] [id=8064]
  0x01b99400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x36640000,0x36740000] [id=7040]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 6464K, used 1582K [0x05cc0000, 0x063c0000, 0x08420000)
  eden space 5760K,  16% used [0x05cc0000, 0x05dabe58, 0x06260000)
  from space 704K,  90% used [0x06310000, 0x063afb70, 0x063c0000)
  to   space 704K,   0% used [0x06260000, 0x06260000, 0x06310000)
 tenured generation   total 85184K, used 51110K [0x08420000, 0x0d750000, 0x25cc0000)
   the space 85184K,  59% used [0x08420000, 0x0b6098d0, 0x0b609a00, 0x0d750000)
 compacting perm gen  total 67328K, used 67218K [0x25cc0000, 0x29e80000, 0x35cc0000)
   the space 67328K,  99% used [0x25cc0000, 0x29e649b0, 0x29e64a00, 0x29e80000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0040e000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\myeclipse.exe
0x77c50000 - 0x77d8c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x760a0000 - 0x76174000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75f90000 - 0x75fda000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77db0000 - 0x77e79000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x76540000 - 0x7658e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76a40000 - 0x76a4a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76700000 - 0x7679d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x768d0000 - 0x7697c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x71b40000 - 0x71bc4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\COMCTL32.dll
0x769a0000 - 0x76a40000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76980000 - 0x76999000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x776b0000 - 0x77751000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77760000 - 0x7777f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76800000 - 0x768cc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x72000000 - 0x72014000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519\eclipse_1206.dll
0x75340000 - 0x75349000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d8b0000 - 0x6db06000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x73a70000 - 0x73aa2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7c360000 - 0x7c3b6000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x75cd0000 - 0x75d1c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d340000 - 0x6d348000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77da5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d860000 - 0x6d86c000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3e0000 - 0x6d3ff000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6d8af000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x75820000 - 0x75836000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x755c0000 - 0x755fb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x75400000 - 0x75417000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75da0000 - 0x75dab000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x75d20000 - 0x75d2c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x6d6c0000 - 0x6d6d3000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\net.dll
0x77780000 - 0x777b5000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x776a0000 - 0x776a6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x757e0000 - 0x7581c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x757d0000 - 0x757d6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x73ec0000 - 0x73ed0000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x73c00000 - 0x73c10000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x74140000 - 0x74152000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x756a0000 - 0x756e4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x74130000 - 0x74138000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x750a0000 - 0x750a5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x75130000 - 0x7514c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x75120000 - 0x75127000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x71b30000 - 0x71b36000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x73080000 - 0x730b8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6d6e0000 - 0x6d6e9000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x36940000 - 0x36999000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\763\1\.cp\swt-win32-3555.dll
0x761e0000 - 0x7633c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x778c0000 - 0x7794f000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x779e0000 - 0x77a5b000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x76180000 - 0x761d7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x74b70000 - 0x74d0e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76a50000 - 0x7769a000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x777c0000 - 0x778b5000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x76590000 - 0x766c7000     C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
0x75e20000 - 0x75f3d000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75e10000 - 0x75e1c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x76340000 - 0x7653e000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x749f0000 - 0x74a30000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x6ca70000 - 0x6ca7f000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\349\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x6ec20000 - 0x6ec78000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x6ebd0000 - 0x6ec1f000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x6dfe0000 - 0x6e061000     C:\ProgramData\Tencent\TSVulFw\TSVulFW.DAT
0x752b0000 - 0x75337000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc\MSVCP80.dll
0x75210000 - 0x752ab000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc\MSVCR80.dll
0x36bc0000 - 0x36c48000     D:\System\KingSoft\Kingsoft Antivirus\kwsui.dll
0x383a0000 - 0x38471000     D:\System\KingSoft\Kingsoft Antivirus\kswebshield.dll
0x74510000 - 0x74523000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x36b80000 - 0x36b94000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\763\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3555.dll
0x74860000 - 0x749f0000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_72d18a4386696c80\gdiplus.dll
0x74160000 - 0x7425b000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x375d0000 - 0x375d8000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\346\1\.cp\os\win32\x86\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x377b0000 - 0x377c0000     D:\Game\U9WSH\nHook.dll
0x766d0000 - 0x766fa000     C:\Windows\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
0x74090000 - 0x740cc000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x75d90000 - 0x75d9e000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x77950000 - 0x779d3000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x73800000 - 0x73805000     C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
0x72fb0000 - 0x72fde000     C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
0x6d840000 - 0x6d848000     D:\Programming\MyEclipse(8.0GA)\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=D:\Programming\Java\jdk1.6.0_10
CLASSPATH=.;D:\Programming\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;D:\Programming\Java\jdk1.6.0_10/lib/dt.jar;D:\Programming\Java\jdk1.6.0_10/lib/tools.jar
PATH=D:/Programming/MyEclipse(8.0GA)/Common/binary/com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013/jre/bin/client;D:/Programming/MyEclipse(8.0GA)/Common/binary/com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;D:\Programming\SqlServer\100\Tools\Binn\;D:\Programming\SqlServer\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\Programming\SqlServer\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\SinoVoice\jTTS 5.0 Desktop\Bin;D:\Digital\QuickTime\QTSystem\;D:\System\ATI\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Programming\Java\jdk1.6.0_10/bin;D:\Programming\Java\jdk1.6.0_10/jre/bin
USERNAME=Loch
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 16 Model 6 Stepping 3, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 16 model 6 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, mmxext, 3dnow, 3dnowext, sse4a

Memory: 4k page, physical 2097151k(1558484k free), swap 4194303k(4194303k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.3-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_13-b03), built on Mar  9 2009 01:15:24 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Sun Aug 14 13:57:40 2011
elapsed time: 18 seconds
```

My myEclipse version is 8.0 .Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Does that only happen with those Spring examples or is it a general problem in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, but there is also a web project which used Spring runs well.I personally think it caused during error reporting like the log says.Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should examine why `nHook.dll` is loaded for Eclipse at all. It seems to come from some game, so maybe your `PATH` environment variable is a little broken.

The `PATH` should always start with `C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows`.

Comment: So you corrected the `PATH` variable, and Eclipse still crashes? Then you should post the new crashdump file, since the file path to `nHook.dll` should be another one. What does this game even have to do with Eclipse?

Comment: It's a assistant to help me play with DOTA in Warcraft. Close it and everything runs well! Thanks a million!